# How to solve "Node is not recognised as an internal or external command, etc"

Tags: node.js

Every time I enter node-v on command prompt, I get the following message: Node is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch.

I have added node to PATH, restarted command prompt, restarted my computer but every time I get that message. I dont know what else I could try to solve this problem! Any help? Thank youu

Comment: what's the output when you run echo $PATH in the command line? And where exactly did you update the value of PATH?

Answer (score 0):

node -v with the space? If it's not that, 99.999% is your path problem. So triple check, make sure the path folder is 100% correct.